# How to display success message PHP code with bootstrap class alert

Tags: php, css

I need to display Success Message while update or insert records in using PHP

this is my HTML code

```
<form action='a.php' methord='post'>
// alert message here
<div class="alert">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
<strong><?php echo $message; ?></strong>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="height:27px;" name="name"\>
<input type="email" class="form-control" style="height:27px;" name="email"\>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" style="height:27px;" name="mobile"\>
<input type="submit" name="user_details" class="btn btn-danger" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Php Code (a.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['user_details']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile= $_POST['mobile'];

    $sql = mysql_query("update user_details set name='$name', email='$email', mobile='$mobile'");
    if($sql==true)
    {
        $message = 'Success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo ''.mysql_error();
    }

}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: see this contact form with php or bootstrap https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

> PHP

```
 if ($error == false) {
$result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
}else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="flash-msg">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
<h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Success!</h4>
</div>';
```

And if you want auto dismiss alert then use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flash-msg").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Same here. I have coded it correctly and it display Notice: Undefined variable results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($sql==true)
{
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Success</div>';
}
else
{
    echo ''.mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: It's still in the same page.